# How to fix ListView.LargeImageList showing images twice

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, imagelist

I am working on a piece of software, which compares memes and helps users organize memes on their computer. As a part of this I am using `Windows.Forms` to build a UI. This UI lets the user add folders to be checked for images, which can be compared to a set of known meme templates.
My issue arises when I try to show the user the found images. To do this I am using a `ListView` and the property `LargeImageList` to contain a tuple of the image and the name of the image file.

Here is the piece of code in question:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    var ic = new ImageCollection();
    var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    fbd.Description = "Select meme folder or image.";
    if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath);
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (!ic.CheckIfImage(file)) continue;
            imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(file));

        }

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add($"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)}", i++);
        }
    }
}
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGGQ3.jpg) is an example of what the user sees when they first load in a folder. When the user tries to load in another folder [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUgrj.jpg) happens. It shows the images from the first folder, with the names of the image files from the second folder.

Does anyone know a fix for this issue? I have tried a variety of options in order to get around the issue. All from trying to clear the `ImageList` used to contain the images, to trying my hand at controlling when the `ListView` updates. None of this has worked. I have also tried googling the issue, but with no luck of finding a fix.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you empty the sub-list inside? imageList1.Images?

Comment: @Pramuka Yes I have tried emptying the sub list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the content of a single folder at the time, then dispose of the objects in your ImageList.

If you instead want to show the content of more than one folder, you need to specify the new index of the image added. You're instead adding a new Item in the ListView using the same index reference:

```
int i = 0;
//(...)
listView1.Items.Add($"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)}", i++);
```

The indexer (`i`) always starts from `0`, thus the ListView Item will use the images in your Imagelist starting from the Image at `Index[0]` each time. The new images won't ever be shown.

You can use the `ImageList.Images.Count` value, representing the number of Images already added to the ImageList, as base and increment the indexer starting from this value:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = imageList1.Images.Count;
    var ic = new ImageCollection();
    var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    fbd.Description = "Select meme folder or image.";
    if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath))
        {
            if (!ic.CheckIfImage(file)) continue;
            imageList1.Images.Add(new Bitmap(file, true));
            listView1.Items.Add($"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)}", i++);
        }
    }
}
```

If you allow to remove an Image from the ListView, you should also remove it from the ImageList: this implies that you need to re-index all the ListView Items starting from the Item that follows the one removed.
Remember to dispose of the Images you remove from the ImageList.

Comment: Thank you so much @Jimi , I feel kinda dumb now